# Restore Failed for server; Cannot open backup device; The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

I am trying to restore a database in sql server management studio in sql 2008 using these steps:

1. Open SQL Management Studio.
2. Right Click on Databases.
3. Choose "Restore Databases..."
4. Enter a "To database" name that is different than the original database.
5. select a "From Database"
6. Observe that a list of files populates in the panel.
7. Click options and make sure "Restore As" names are unique.
8. Click OK
9. Observe the error below.

[image: Error Message]

What am I doing wrong?

I can see the error says that a file is missing, but it does not tell me which file is missing so that I can at least get some clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It says it can’t open your backup device. Have you confirmed the backup files exist? If you know where they are located, restore from a file and navigate to the particular backup you need.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.howtogeek.com/50354/restoring-a-sql-database-backup-using-sql-server-management-studio/ you need to know where your backup files are located. Look in your scheduled SQL tasks and see where the backup was configured to write to, assuming you were using SQL to back up and not some 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

Select from file and Specify the File location.  Be sure you have access to the folder.  I had similar issue trying to recover database.  Also be sure to specify new file name is unique if you are not overwriting current database.

I never overwrite current database, I restore as new database.  But File name/Locations must be changed for MDF & LDF file.  Those are all the possible things I've done incorrectly before.  I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what was happening...  There was a new backup product installed by the systems guy that was backup the database to remote storage.   It was taking a full backup.  Subsequent incremental backups were pointing to that back up.  because that backup was not available we got restore failed error.  To fix the systems guy changed the remote backup to be a "copy only"